# maximum call stack size jQuery version 1.9.0

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

my question involves bad written code, it works but its messy, anyways, it's just for experimental purposes, i was trying to implement a "like system", a user clicks on a button, the object id associated with the button is sent to a script via ajax and a mysql table is updated with the user's like data-which would be the object id. To do this, i had to use php to echo out the object, and a like button with a javascript function attached to it like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($tempest);$i++)

{echo "<div class='posts'>
\"".$row2['screen_name']."\" 
<img src=\"".$row2['avatar']."\" width=50 height=50/><br>
 added a new page to the magic title
  \"".$row3['magic_name']."\"
   <br>
<img src=\"".$row1['p_name']."\">
<div id=\"".$i."\">
<a href='Javascript:penda(\"".$wholei."\",\"".$i."\")'> //this is the javascript function
<img name='mpe' src='images/like_outline.png'> //this is the like button
</a></div>
</div>";
}
```

i know echoing out html is w=just wrong, but like i said, it's just for fun, when using jquery version 1.8.3 to do the ajax request here it is:

```
function penda(item, itid) {
    itid = itid + "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "kumbatian.php",
        data: {
            penzi: item
        },
        success: function (ful) {
            if (ful == 'win') document.getElementById('win').innerHTML += "YOU WIN!!";
        }
    });
    document.getElementById(itid).innerHTML = "<a href='unlike()'><img src='images/like.png' /></a>";
}
```

i would get the following error, i'm using chrome: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, what i think it meant was that the number of 'likes' being echoed were to many to be attached to the function penda, the size of array $tempest is 6, so there are six like buttons. When i upgraded to jquery version 1.9.0, there was no such error and everything worked fine, so this is my question:
1.) How many buttons would need to be echoed in the format above for the same error to occur in version 1.9.0?
2.)What better way to attach all those like buttons to the function penda() is there to avoid the error i experienced?

EDIT:
as per requested, here's the html output:

```
<div id="0"><a href="Javasctipt:penda("mna4","0")"> <img name="mpe" src="images/like_outline.png"> </a></div>

  <div id="1"><a href="Javasctipt:penda("mna4","1")"> <img name="mpe" src="images/like_outline.png"> </a></div>

  <div id="2"><a href="Javasctipt:penda("mna4","2")"> <img name="mpe" src="images/like_outline.png"> </a></div>

  <div id="4"><a href="Javasctipt:penda("mna4","4")"> <img name="mpe" src="images/like_outline.png"> </a></div>

  <div id="5"><a href="Javasctipt:penda("mna4","5")"> <img name="mpe" src="images/like_outline.png"> </a></div>

  <div id="6"><a href="Javasctipt:penda("mna4","6")"> <img name="mpe" src="images/like_outline.png"> </a></div>
```

that's it.

Comment: Is there any recursion involved here? I dont see any

Comment: Does the "Uncaught RangeError" occur at page load or does it occur when you click the like button?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im you mean is there a loop? yes, the for loop that echos the like buttons from the array tempest.

Comment: @darshanags the error occurs when i click the like button.

Comment: @EmmanuelImwene can you modify your question to include you html output please? (not php)

Comment: @darshanags i have done so, kindly see the edits.

Comment: @EmmanuelImwene thanks. At first glance I doubt that this has to do with the number of buttons on the page. I'll do some digging and get back to you with what I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with outputting HTML with PHP.

What is wrong, however, is your result. As the colour coding clearly shows you, your quotes aren't properly escaped.

Try this:

```
... href="javascript:penda(&quot;mna4&quot;,0)" ...
```

By using HTML entities, you avoid conflict between the quotes. Just make sure that string value isn't anything that may have quotes, otherwise you'll need to be cleverer.

Comment: thanks! I managed to find another way around it, but your answer does help nevertheless, this was quite a long time ago i asked this, but thanks anyways.